# How to randomly select a line within msql in a table and display result on webpage and send result to 2 email addresses as well?

Tags: mysql, database, email, select, random

Basically I am setting up a subscription application of name and email on my website which I am currently building. I have tested out the subscription form and all is working as it sends the data to the msql database and into the appropriate table (subscriptions) then into the 2 fields (subscriptionname, subscriptionemail).
With this I wish to once a month randomly draw a line out of the fields (which would have their name and email) and display this (only their name along with some other text such as "name is the winner of this month's random draw" etc) on the homepage of the website. (Might do as TWO draws same time every month. Unsure yet).

I'd want this to also send an email to the winner using obviously the email address it has as well as send to a predefined email address to me. (This is so I know exactly who has won it as of course there could be 2 or more people with the same name so I would not know which one won it. So within this email it would simply provide me with the name and email so I could supply the prize.)

I really hope someone would be able to help as I am completely clueless as what to do as I know little in the world of codes especially something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what language you are using so I will write in python.

Rewritten in PHP

```
<?php
// your MySql specific parameters
$my_host = "localhost";
$my_user = "user";
$my_pass = "password";
$my_db = "test";


// Connecting, selecting database
$link = mysql_connect($my_host, $my_user, $my_pass);
mysql_select_db($my_db);

// Mysql fast random from http://wanderr.com/jay/order-by-slow/2008/01/30/
// Assuming MySql table called users
$query = "SELECT * FROM subscriptions T JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(MAX(ID)*RAND()) AS ID FROM USERS) AS x ON T.ID >= x.ID LIMIT 1;";

$result = mysql_query($query);

// get the user
$user = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$user_email = user['Subscriptionemail'];
$user_name = user['subscriptionname'];

// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($result);

// Closing connection
mysql_close($link);

//
// Email part
//

// specific to you
$HOST = 'My smtp server';
$my_email = 'me@my_domain.com';
$server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST);


$text = "Hello " + $user_name + " you have won the prize!";
mail($user_email, "You won!", $text, "From: " + $my_email);


$text = $user_name + " has won the prize! Their email is " + $user_email + ".";
mail($my_email, "New winner!", $text, "From: " + $my_email);
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply but this is to go straight into the website so I guess it would need html or php (I'd assume php as its a functioning process)
Basic info for the server if you would use those so i wouldnt need any guess work.
table: subscriptions
field1: subscriptionname
field2: Subscriptionemail

I really appreciate that you responded because frankly I'm clueless when it comes to any sort of coding. I tend to understand a decent amount but when it comes to writing I'd instantly be lost.
Cheers